# Ignore Pending Product Reviews in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

By default, Magento *only* displays existing ratings/reviews on category page template `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` like this:

```
<?php if ($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I adopted this in my own theme and included a reasonable fallback so as not to break the flow/layout of the page.
However, if there are 0 reviews *and* a review is posted but **not** approved, nothing is displayed (*see attached image*).

[image: Pending Product Review Bug]

```
<?php if ($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short'); ?>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="ratings">
  <div class="rating-box">
    <div class="rating" style="width: 0%;"></div>
  </div>
  <span class="amount"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>#client-reviews">0 <?php echo $this->__('Review(s)'); ?></a></span>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added an additional condition which, while not the prettiest solution, does the trick.

```
<?php if ($_product->getRatingSummary() && $_product->getRatingSummary()->getData('reviews_count') > 0): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short'); ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="ratings">
        <div class="rating-box">
          <div class="rating" style="width: 0%"></div>
        </div>
        <span class="amount"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>#client-reviews">0 <?php echo $this->__('Review(s)'); ?></a></span>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```